# NestJS Fundamentals Course / Use transactions: compilation error

Tags: transactions, repository

I am following the NestJS fundamentals course and I am getting stuck with the "[Use transactions](https://learn.nestjs.com/courses/591712/lectures/23193771)" section:

First of all, it seems to me that the course contains a typo in the import:

```
// ... other imports
import { Entity } from '../events/entities/event.entity';
```

Should be: `import { Event } ...`

But then, after having completed the section, I realize that I have this compilation error:

> [Nest] 507493  - 04/01/2022, 5:13:17 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No
> repository for "Event" was found. Looks like this entity is not
> registered in current "default" connection? RepositoryNotFoundError:
> No repository for "Event" was found. Looks like this entity is not
> registered in current "default" connection?
> at RepositoryNotFoundError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
> at new RepositoryNotFoundError (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/src/error/RepositoryNotFoundError.ts:10:9)
> at EntityManager.getRepository (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:964:19)
> at Connection.getRepository (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/src/connection/Connection.ts:354:29)
> at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm.providers.js:17:30)
> at Injector.instantiateClass (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:333:55)
> at callback (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:48:41)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:122:24)
> at Injector.loadInstance (/home/vmalep/Dvpt/NestJS/course/iluvcoffee/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:52:9)

The code is available here: https://github.com/vmalep/nestJSCourse/tree/useTransacionError

I have tried different solution, but to no avail and the course does not give any contact to get support (despite the fact that we have to pay for it...). So I am asking for help in this forum. It will be highly appreciated!

Best regards,
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

This morning I restarted the lesson about useTransaction, going step by step and making sure the code was running after each of them and I completed the lesson without error. I have been through the code to look for any significant difference between the broken branch and the new one, but I could not find anything convincing. I just notice that the error I had appeared again after having added `Event` in the line 9 of the
`coffees.modules.ts` file and disappeared once the `import { Event } from '../events/entities/event.entity';` was added in the same file...

There is still this typo in the course in the file `coffees.service.ts`: `import { Entity }` in place of `Event`.

Answer (score 0):

At event.entity.ts, add @Entity() to declare that this class is an entity. The example code is as below:

```
@Entity()
export class Event {
```